# POSTGRESQL Query for join in the one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Hi i craeted a table in postgresql that include first_id and seconde_id and they could be Repetitious. i wanna write a query that back me below result:
for example i search for first_id="3" and get this result:

```
first_id seconde_id
3        4
3        6
3        9
3        8
```

now i wanna use the seconde_id as first_id, this mean for each seconde_id, i wanna write the first query. for example first_id=4,first_id=6,first_id=9 and ...
how to write it in one query?

i use the WITH RECURSICE but it didnt work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE first_id in (SELECT seconde_id FROM tablename WHERE first_id = 3);
```